# image not cached when loaded with meta refresh

Tags: .htaccess, tags, refresh, browser-cache

Not really an issue, but how come images cached in .htaccess with :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=6048000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

are reloaded every time when the url of the page is called by a meta tag

```
<http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=page_with_large_jpg.php"> )
```

This meta tag is on another php script... php scripts are only cached 1 second :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, no-cache, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

In most situations the cache looks good, if I enter the url of a page containing a large jpg image manually, or call this page by clicking on a link to it, the jpg is clearly cached (provided I visited this page/image previously of course), and so displayed instantly, but if the page containing the large jpg is called by meta refresh tag in the head section, the image is loaded again, taking a few seconds or more to be displayed entirely if it's very large !

Is there a way to prevent this ?

Comment: Have you checked the request/response headers in both cases? Whilst the image may look like it's cached (or not), the definitive answer is to check the headers. Are different request headers being sent with the meta-refresh?

Comment: No. I don't have a sniffer installed on my computer...

Comment: "No" or you "don't know"? Have you examined the HTTP request? If by "sniffer" you mean a tool that reports the HTTP request/response headers then this is built into the browser - no additional software required.